Where Clause value from a Cell in Excel to retrieve data from a Cloud Database
I have a query that I have to run regularly. Using Get Data function via ODBC, I am able to import data perfectly fine for a static SQL code. However, is it possible to parse a value from the Cell in the Where clause of the SQL Code?
For Example:
Select A, B, C from XYZ Where A IN (1,2,3)
Now if the Cell value is 4,5,6
then upon refreshing, the values within IN (.....) gets replaced with 4,5,6
I have come across solutions such as using Macros or Parameters but have following restrictions:

Can't use macros because Macro enabled file is not supported by Power Automate. There are additional processes and hence can't depend on Macro.
The data set is really huge so I can't pull 100% of data and then filter using a parameter.

Any advice is appreciated. Please help a brother out :)
I have tried creating Parameters, but it seems it can only filter results. I actually want to modify the query depending upon the cell value.
